# What happens when you logical not a float?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, logic, logical-operators

I assume this just returns an int. Is there anything else going on I should be aware of? C/C++ differences?

```
float a = 2.5;
!a; // What does this return? Int? Float?
```

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969620/c-float-to-bool-conversion)

Comment: _!a_ for float can be rewritten as _a==0.0_

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Regarding C++, quoting C++11 §5.3.1/9:

> The operand of the logical negation operator `!` is contextually converted to `bool`; its value is `true` if the converted operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. The type of the result is `bool`.

So what's *really* relevant here is the behavior of `static_cast<bool>(some_float)` – quoting §4.12/1:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

Putting those together, `2.5f` is a non-zero value and will consequently evaluate to `true`, which when negated will evaluate to `false`. I.e., `!a` == `false`.

---

Regarding C, quoting C99 §6.5.3.3/5:

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is `0` if the value of its operand compares unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

I.e. the net result is the same as with C++, excepting the type.

Comment: Thanks! I assume this means in C I'd get an int?

Comment: @NathanFig: Right, the result of `!` in C is always an `int`.

Comment: @ildjarn I have seen you use `<!-- language: lang-ml -->` in F# edits to force syntax highlighting but there is also `<!-- language: lang-f#-->` so why not use that?

Comment: @CetinSert : When I first started using SO only the former worked, I simply continue to use it out of habit. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn I am glad I could still reach you with this primitive mode of socializing, despite StackOverflow not giving its users anything better. You are doing a great job with your edits though! Keep them up. It is nice to notice your touches on many F# questions.

Comment: @CetinSert : Thanks. :-] And the one other option for contacting someone is to go to [Chat.SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and create a new room, then go to the person's chat profile and send them an invitation to that room (it will show them an inbox notification).

Comment: I wonder if 0.0 can be represent precisely, if not, then 0.0 == 0.0 will be false. (as we know, we shouldn not compare two float point value diretly)

Answer (score 9):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969620/c-float-to-bool-conversion)

A float will be converted to false if its exactly 0.0f,
It will be also true if its not exacly 0.0f!
Inifinity will also be converted to true.

Comment: I was not sure about the negation of infinity, so i checked out here is the output http://ideone.com/WWoJB#view_edit_box

Comment: if exactly +0.0f, -0.0f has a bit set and inverted still has a bit set

Comment: @dwelch I did not know that, i guess you learn something new everyday

Comment: that is my understanding is you can have the sign bit with exponent and mantissa still showing zero.

Answer (score -1):

See for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   float a = 2.5;

   if ( !a )
       std::cout << !a << "\n";

   else
       std::cout << !a << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem with "seeing for yourself" is that you can observe undefined or implementation-defined behavior, which only tells you what happens on your particular platform/compiler, which is not useful when knowing what to expect in terms of _well-defined_ behavior.

Comment: You can't "expect" anything from "implementation-defined" behavior. So what's "well-defined" mean to you?

Comment: Exactly, which is why "see for yourself" is a useless answer if the behavior is implementation-defined. Thanks for agreeing with my point. :-P

Comment: Both branches of your `if`/`else` block do exactly the same thing, may as well not have the `if`/`else`.