# Is it safe to cast a float with value 0.0f to boolean?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, boolean, floating-point-precision

I know that due to precision errors, a `float` varibale should be checked to equal a value always *with some tolerance*. But what's is that even the case if I manually set the `float` variable to `0.0f`?

For example there is a function returning a distance.

```
float distance()
{
    float value;
    if(/* ... */)
    {
        // ...
        return value;
    }
    else return 0.0f;
}
```

Can I cast the result to bool safely?

```
if(distance())
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: That would be entirely confusing to a future developer.. why not set a constant called `ZERO_DISTANCE` and just say, `if(distance() != ZERO_DISTANCE)`?

Comment: @0A0D i do not think that it is much better style to compare float values against defines or consts. Also it is bad style to test `if( /* float expression */)` why not simply test for ìf( abs(value) <= epsilon)`

Comment: When I return `0.0f` then that really means a distance of zero. Therefore it won't be confusing. The question is if I can rely on the result to be cast to `false` later.

Comment: @0A0D no. thou shall not test equality on floats.

Comment: @Elazar Rubbish. Thou can perfectly well test for equality on floats if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: Because the OP isn't testing if its less than or equal to an epsilon? You can have a negative distance too, so `abs` isn't needed always. At least in this case, he is testing if its __zero__, nothing else.

Comment: Never check a float against 0.0... except when you want to know if the value of that float is 0.0.

Comment: There are no casts in this code. The question is about a **conversion**. A **cast** is something you write in your code that tells the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Comment: And, no, it's **not** automatically a good thing to test floating-point values for "nearly equal". If you don't understand what's happening in the calculation that produced a value, fudging a test won't fix it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Relational operators on fuzzy quantities fundamentally have four states: X is definitely bigger, Y is definitely bigger, they're two close to tell, or they're not comparable (e.g. one or both is NaN).  Sometimes it's better to detect things that are too close to tell as equal, but sometimes it's better to maintain a strictly-consistent ranking and promise that the sets of things that compare equal form equivalence relations.

Comment: @supercat - that is one way to design them, but I have yet to see an answer or comment suggesting that approach to beginners who aren't in control of their floating-point calculations; it's always "see if they're nearly the same because, after all, you never really know..."

Comment: @PeteBecker: Instead of saying "relational operators" I should have said "relational comparisons".  From a language-design perspective, it's probably better to have the *operators* impose a ranking which is consistent and whose definition of "equality" forms an equivalence relation, than have them do anything else, but code which needs to compare things will likely need to recognize the fuzzy nature of comparisons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write:

```
if(distance())
```

you are checking whether the float is zero or not.

Your code is equivalent to

```
if(distance() != 0)
```

This is perfectly safe to do, and only you can determine whether or not it has the meaning that you require.

Comment: Can't you say that both, checking for a float to be zero or not and casting it to boolean is the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same.

Comment: @David: Well, they are, really.

Comment: `you are not casting to a boolean` Yes, you are. Read 6.4.1 to discover how the `if` statement works.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it's an implicit conversion, not a cast, technically.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The phrase used in the standard is "contextually converted".

Comment: Oh, you're right that it's not a "cast". But the conversion does occur.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Reading this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833790/what-happens-when-you-logical-not-a-float, it would seem that `static_cast<bool>(some_float)` is compared against `0.0f` so I guess it is a cast. I've edited to remove the contentious wording.

Comment: @David: That's better. :) (Though I'm still not sure that you've addressed the OP's concerns about floating-point precision)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't quite follow that last comment. Surely it's fairly evident that `(0.0f == 0)`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, not necessarily [evident]. I believe that actually forms the crux of the OP's question, since he goes out of his way to talk about floating-point imprecision. I think that an answer to this question _explains why_ and/or _convinces that_ `(0.0f == 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an exact value that you expect, there's absolutely no reason not to compare against that exact value. It's only when you perform a computation and get an inexact result that it's unsafe to compare against an exact value. And you generally want to assume that any floating point computation will give an inexact result.

In your case, you're returning a constant, so it's safe to compare to a constant.

Another time you'd want to compare against an exact value is to avoid singularities. For example, `x == 0.0 ? 1.0 : sin(x)/x`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're asking if you can assume that the following line won't fire.

```
assert(0.0f);
```

**Yes.** You can assume that.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes; 0.0f is representable by the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). However, the question is that will it be always zero, when you expect it to be and not the next floating point number.

I wouldn't do it, though.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this standard. That's all I want.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct to worry about floating-point inaccuracy, but you're also correct to suppose that it isn't a problem in this case.

The likelihood of your computer storing `0.0f` as anything other than *precisely* zero is astronomical, and a conversion of precisely floating-point zero to boolean is well-defined.