# Why does sizeof(!5.6) give an output 2?

Tags: c, sizeof

Even if we declare `float a=5.6` then `printf("%d",sizeof(!a))` outputs `2`.
Why does it output size of integer?

Comment: What does `!` do in this context?

Comment: size of integer is not 2

Comment: @Alex How do you know that for sure?

Comment: Read this answer from a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833790/what-happens-when-you-logical-not-a-float

Comment: @Alex : I am using 16-bit environment.

Comment: It's scary seeing people assert that `sizeof(int)` can't be 2.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's the negation (logical not) operator in C...

Comment: I know that, I wanted the OP to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `!` operator returns an integral type, likely `int`. `sizeof(int) == 2` on your architecture, apparently.

Comment: Thats not true because this is a C question. In C, ! returns an int.

Comment: Whoops, missed that this was C, not C++. Edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: @Dibya C has had `bool` since 1999.

Comment: @Casey: that's a library type, not fundamental. The fundamental boolean type is _Bool.

Comment: @H2CO3 in a specific header only. Hence "library type". If you forget to include the header, the compiler pukes.

Answer (score 3):

The `!` operator doesn't return the type of the operand. If you perform a NOT on a `float`, you're not going to get a `float` back. You are going to get an `int` with the logically opposite value of the initial `float`.

Comment: Are you sure, that is what happens? don't you think it performs an implicit cast to an integer first?

Comment: @TommyA First of all, there's no such thing as an "implicit cast", it's an oxymoron. Casts, by definition, are explicit. Explicit type conversion = type casting, implicit type conversion = type promotion or type coercion. Secondly, no, there's no implicit conversion. The floating-point number `0.1` is considered true because it's not zero, although it **would** be zero if it was converted to an integral type (truncation) beforehand. (Moral: don't teach others C (and stuff) if you don't know it.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know how many question marks are needed for showing people the difference, between asking a question, and "teaching" someone. Mine was clearly asking a question, which you, thank you for that, answered. The moral of your story is real nice, but please improve on the maturity part of it. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9833830/1787973 , `!E` is equivalent to `0==E` and as a consequence, it's of type `int`.

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
>   equivalent to (0==E).

`sizeof(int)` is 2 on your 16 bits architecture, explaining why `sizeof(!a)` outputs `2` on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

This could help.

```
void main(){
    int x = !4.3;
    printf("%d",x);//This will print 0
    printf("%d",sizeof(0));//This will print 2
    printf("%d",sizeof(!4.3));//Will print 2
}
```

You will find that `!4.3` will return a 0. Hence `sizeof(!4.3)` = `sizeof(0)` = `2`(as 0 is an integer) so `sizeof(!4.3)`will be 2 .

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning. What does the value have to do with the size?

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time. Having `uint8_t x = 0` followed by `sizeof(x)` will have the `sizeof` evaluate to `1`, so your example doesn't make much sense. `sizeof` is about types, not values.