# Convert a small C++ code snippet to a C# code

Tags: c#, c++

I got this code which was written in C++:

```
static double e[66];
if (!e[0]) {
   // Do Something
}
```

It does not compile in Visual Studio saying that Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'double'.

What is the propar way to write it in C#?

Comment: What should `!`applied to a ``double` value actually mean? Equal to `0.0`??

Comment: ! is for bools not doubles,explain what you want to do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833790/what-happens-when-you-logical-not-a-float, same is valid for double

Comment: In c, zero would be false and anything else would be true.  So the equivalent in c# would be if(e[0] != 0)

Comment: Why you guys downvote my question and then ask obliviously sillier questions? Anyway for those not so frustrated; i don't know what this if statement is supposed to check. Actually i am about to find out if i convert the code. Thank you

Comment: Why you post code-translation request instead of a question? And why are you "translating" code when you don't apparently know either source **or** destination language?

Comment: change it to `static double e[66];
if(e[0] != 0) {
   // Do Something
}`

Comment: I said for the non-frustrated people willing to help. Guys like you that do not want to help indeed could just downvote and feel happy because of that. Anyway i believe that jdweng's suggestion is what i am looking for. Thank you and sorry for not being able to vote for your solution. Cheers

Comment: don't worry, I gave you a thump up and supplied an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not consider boolean as an int/double that can be used as a true/false statement.

You will have to write something like:

`if(e[0] == 0.0) ..`

Also, you can't have a local static variable like in C++. You can declare it as a class member, initialize it in the static constructor and then use it.

Comment: Change the "!=" to "==" and it's correct (remember, the original C++ used was "if ( ! e[0])" - note the '!' operator).

Comment: You are correct Dave.. I got confused for a second. Thank you!